# Does there exists $F\subseteq K$ with $[K:F]=2$ where $F\simeq K\simeq \mathbb{Q}(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Haven't seen this posted here before. This is another old prelim problem. My feeling is that no such field extension exists. Why I think this is that $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ has no index 2 subgroups, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem) stating that any field $F$ strictly between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(x)$. It is easier to show that $[\Bbb{Q}(x):F]<\infty$ for any such $F$.

Comment: Subgroups don't enter the scene here. If $L/K$ is Galois with Galois group $G$, then the intermediate fields $F$ such that $[F:K]=2$ correspond to index two subgroups of $G$. But this doesn't mesh with the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the fields $F,K$ be given by $F=Q(x^2),\;K=Q(x)$.

Comment: Cool, but why is $[K:F]=2$. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: $x$ satisfies the quadratic polynomial $f \in Q(x^2)[t]$ given by $f(t) = t^2-x^2$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(x):\mathbb{Q}(x^2)] \le 2$. But $x \notin :\mathbb{Q}(x^2)$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}(x):\mathbb{Q}(x^2)] > 1$.